# How to determine Acrobat Reader version without using Registry

Tags: c#, .net

I know that Acrobat reader is installed,but i wanna know that which version of acrobat installed?
But without using Registry key.
There is any Acrobat reader function for getting it?

Thanks in advance

I used following Code but its throw exception at some places

```
RegistryKey adobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Adobe");
        if (adobe != null)
        {
            RegistryKey acroRead = adobe.OpenSubKey("Acrobat Reader");
            if (acroRead != null)
            {
                string[] acroReadVersions = acroRead.GetSubKeyNames();

                string versionNos = "";
                string ResultAcrobat ="";
                foreach (string versionNumber in acroReadVersions)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToDecimal(versionNumber) >= 9)
                    {
                        ResultAcrobat = "OK";
                    }
                    versionNos += ",Version v" + versionNumber;
                }
                versionNos = versionNos.Remove(0, 1);
                AcrobatReader = versionNos;

                if (Convert.ToString(dr["ResultAcrobat"]) == "")
                {
                    ResultAcrobat = "Error";

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, but it is more hackish than reading the registry (which holds the actual application being opened).

My suggestion if you can't read the registry is this:

- Find all files names `AcroRd32.exe` in the program files folder, in my case under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe`;
- Get the file version from the executables found using this code:

  ```
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe", "AcroRd32.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

  // determine which one to use
  string pathToAdobeExe = files.First();

  string version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(pathToAdobeExe).ProductVersion;
  ```

Comment: Actually i already used registry and got the version and its installed path also but its give error at some client. That means its behave differently at different location

Comment: @abhishekk Sounds to me like you are asking an XY question. Shouldn't you look at the error you get on client machines, and if you can't explain it, ask about that?